# AWS sagemaker with fbprophet algorithm

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to generate some realtime predictions using fbProhet,  AWS sagemaker .
Here what I am trying.

1. created a dockerfile which will install fbprohet library and copy the myfile.py file and added
   ENTRYPOINT ["python", "./myfile.py"], where myfile.py contains the code to analyze the sample and upload the result as .csv to s3.
2. created docker image using the above file and pushed to ECR
3. created a training job in sagemaker by referring the above docker image.
4. created model from the training job
5. created endpoint using the model

But it is getting failed as it couldn't find and model artifact in S3.  and to test I have created a .zip file and uploaded to s3 bucket. but still the endpoint is getting failed as there is a ping error "the default variant did not pass the ping health check".

I am not sure what I am missing.

the dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3-slim
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget && apt-get install -y curl && apt-get install -y git && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -L https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/raw/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
ENV PYENV_ROOT $HOME/.pyenv
ENV PATH $PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /tmp/install_miniconda.sh && \
 /bin/bash /tmp/install_miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda
ENV PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade \
    pip \
    setuptools \
    wheel

RUN conda install -c conda-forge Prophet

COPY myfile.py .
RUN chmod +x myfile.py
COPY requirement.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirement.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "./myfile.py"
```

and myfile is :

```
import boto3
import logging
import json
import base64
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
from time import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

from configparser import ConfigParser
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import configparser
from prophet import Prophet

def test():
    bucket = 'bucket-test'
    file = 'test.xlsx'
    df = pd.read_excel(f"s3://{bucket}/{file}")
    df.columns.values
    column1=(df.columns.values[1])
    column2=(df.columns.values[10])
    parsedTimestampColumn=(df[column1])
    parsedMetricsColumn=(df[column2])
    data={'ps':parsedTimestampColumn , 'pd':parsedMetricsColumn}
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    m = Prophet(yearly_seasonality=True)
    m.fit(df1)
    future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=500,freq='H')
    forecast = m.predict(future)
    forecast[['ps', 'w', 'w_l', 'w_u']].tail()
    fig1 = m.plot(forecast)
    fig2 = m.plot_components(forecast)
    
    results=pd.concat([df1[['pd']],forecast[['ps', 'w', 'w_l', 'w_u']]],axis=1)
    results['error']=results['y']-results['w']
    results["uncertainity"]=results['w_u']-results['w_l']
    results[results['error'].abs()> 1.2*results['uncertainity']]
    results['Anomalies']=results.apply(lambda x:'Yes' if (np.abs(x['error'])>1.2*x['uncertainity'] )else 'No',axis=1)
    result_Dataframe = pd.DataFrame(results)
    print(result_Dataframe.tail())
    return result_Dataframe
     

if __name__=="__main__":
  test()
```

can any one guide me what I am missing here to create a successful model and endpoint ?

Comment: I'm assuming you're able to run the training job and create a model from it, and not able to invoke the endpoint successfully. Are you using a built-in container for inference, or the same custom docker? SageMaker inference needs a model_fn(), input_fn(), output_fn() for inference. See [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/adapt-inference-container.html).

Comment: Thanks @durga_sury .
yes, Iam able to create the training job and model from it. but no able to create the endpoint.
I am using a custom container, which is created using the above docker file and I am using only one python file posted above.
I am not sure how to make it work. It would be good if you can help me on how to add the functions o my examples 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hi @Tes - were you able to test it out with the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/adapt-inference-container.html) I shared earlier? Your `myfile.py` needs to have a model_fn(), predict_fn(), input_fn() and output_fn(). You'll essentially add code to decode the input, load model, make predictions, and encode the outputs. See this doc - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html for how SageMaker works with docker for hosting.

Comment: Hi @durga_sury , no I couldn't complete it. Thanks for the inputs. Let me try it with your inputs now. Thanks a lot 

Comment: I couldn't pass it through. :(